# Version exception error when connect to database using C# and SQL Server 2014

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014

The connection to database is working if I am using `SqlDataSource` object but it's not working when I am using C# code.

See the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTLvn.jpg

The problem is the data set returning  null while i can track the query on SQL Server profiler.
and i test the query on SQL query editor it returning a result can you told me what the wrong on the code:

Code to return result on Data Set

Code Sample:

```
 static public DataSet GetData(string SqlStatement)
    {
        DataSet datasetdata=new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection connection =
        new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Undp_PortalConnectionString1"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(SqlStatement, connection);             
            adapter.Fill(datasetdata);
            return datasetdata;
              }

 }



SqlStatement = Select * From Portal_PersonalInfo  Where email = 'waleed.obyed@undp.org'
```

Table :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQMnX.jpg

Comment: The data set always return null

Comment: Well - in that sample data you're showing - there is **no row** with that e-mail address - that's why your data set comes back empty......

Comment: i update the sample data include the email address

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this **while the connection is OPEN** - by default, the `SqlDataAdapter` will open and close the connection as needed - you never get a chance to check while it's open.

If you *open the connection* yourself

```
connection.Open();
```

before the call to `.Fill()` - then you will see the `ServerVersion` is quite nicely filled on the `connection` property:

[image]

Comment: The problem now the data set always return null see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem from the DataSet file on the App_Code called DataSet.xsd this file add to *datasetdata* Table called ES_ICTCR see the photo, i delete this file i think because it has common name **DataSet.xsd**.
check the Table Count= **2**.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f66JJ.jpg